# Listbox items still present in code behind although removed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a listbox control on my page(which is in a modal dialog box). When I remove an item from the listbox (using Javascript) I'm using some jQuery to do a postback i.e.

```
                    __doPostBack(invisibleButton.name, '');
```

If I had 2 items, some javascipt removes one item but when the code behind is called in the postback, listbox.items.count still equals 2.

What can I do to get around this?

Any ideas?

Comment: When you remove the item using Javascript, you're doing it outside the ASP.NET framework. In other words, your page doesn't know you removed it. You'll have to tell the page on postback that you want it gone.

Comment: Yep...and I'm trying to remember how to do that?

Comment: You could do it a couple ways. You're using __doPostBack, which takes a parameter. You could set the parameter to the id of the ListBox item you removed, then check the __EVENTARGUMENT Request item in your PageLoad and remove it there.